# Outlook rest api redirect "too many times" while logging in to outlook account

Tags: php, laravel-5, outlook

I am using outlook rest api in my Laravel project with Microsoft graph and outh2 package. Everything was working fine till yesterday, today suddenly I am facing this issue, third time I am facing this problem and I resolved this by creating another app in Microsoft application registration portal. So this time I can't figure out any proper solution.

Error screen shot:

[image: Error screen shot]

Comment: What happens when you clear your cookies?

Comment: nothing happened.

Comment: @Joel Fazio i have cleared cookies number of time but no luck still.

Comment: What are you using to make HTTP requests? In curl I've solved this problem in the past with the following flags (in PHP): CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS and CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION

Comment: @Joel Fazio sorry to inform you late , i have resolve this issue. Actually i am using laravel and  .env was not reflecting variable values. So i used php artisan config:clear.

Comment: @MKDEV, your comment should be put up as an answer. `php artisan config:clear`